# Creating a computer account in AD using PowerShell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, azure, scripting, azure-powershell

I want to create a new computer object in an AD domain.

Below is the script I am using. Can someone tell where should create credential object for SRV1? In domain controller or in computer? If credential object for SRV1 is created in domain controller, how will computer get value of CredSRV1 which is used in joining the computer to the domain?

```
#Creating a new computer in the domain
$NCHT = @{
    Name = 'User'
    DNSHostName = 'user.domain.com'
    Description = ''
    Path = 'OU=xyz,DC=domain,DC=com'
}
New-ADComputer @NCHT

#Creating a credential object for SRV1
$ASRV1 = 'SRV1/Administrator'
$PSRV1 = 'P@SSW0RD'
$PSSRV1 = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $PSRV1 -AsPlainText -Force
$CredSRV1 = [pscredential]::New($ASRV1,$PSSRV1)

#Creating a script to join SRV1
$SB = {
    $ARK = 'domain/Administrator'
    $PRK = 'P@SSW0RD'
    $PSRK = ConvertTo-SecureString - String $PRK -AsPlainText -Force
    $CredRK = [pscredential::New($ARK,$PSRK)
    $DJHT = @{
        DomainName = 'domain.com'
        OUPath = 'OU=xyz,DC=domain,DC=com'
        Credential = $CredRK
        Restart = $false
        }
        Add-Computer @DJHT
}

#Joining the computer to the domain
Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value '*'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SRV1 -Credential $CredSRV1 -Force

#Restarting SRV1
Restart-Computer -ComputerName SRV1 -Credential $CredSRV1 -Force

#Viewing the resulting computer accounts for domain
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties DNSHostName, LastLogonDate | Format-Table -Property Name, DNSHostname, Enabled
```

Comment: Where did you copy the script from?

Comment: from a book. @GregAskew

Comment: Before getting into scripts, you should run the commands individually to see how they work. You need to run the commands on SRV1, where you are specifying the credentials for SRV1.

Comment: A credential object is created in domain controller. $CredSRV1 is in Creating credential object. Now i need value of CredSRV1 in my machine(PC) to attach it to a domain! How should i do it? @GregAskew

Comment: You literally need to run the script on SRV1. Can you do that?

Comment: This script demonstrates a complete lack of understanding of the concepts involved including Powershell in general. It is hard to determine where to begin to help without writing and delivering the script myself, which we don’t do here. More time and effort needs to be put in to understanding the concepts so that you know the right questions to ask. I suspect you’ll answer them yourself.

Comment: If you can't help, then please don't add comment. If it was possible for me to answer myself, then why would i bring this problem here? @Appleoddity

Comment: @munishhh - the comment is critical, but not meant to insult you. It is clear that you lack a basic understanding of what the code you wrote is trying to do. Your question is not as straightforward about CredSrv1. That is not the issue. The issue is that this script will not work in any way, shape, or form and you need to learn and understand what the code you are writing does. Then come back and ask one or more specific questions about any remaining problems. Which you'll probably answer yourself. There's nothing to work with here to even begin to answer.

Answer (score 0):

credential data is created neither on DC nor on srv1. It's store locally on where you run the script.

Comment: Ok. Now could you please clarify me, In above lines of code, which block of code should i run on domain controller and which on computer(computer that i want to join to the domain, here SRV1)

Comment: You run it on any machine that is domain joined as long as you have proper permission

Comment: @munishhh LOL which part of my answer didn't answer the question? And which part you see "critique". It only shows you don't have very basic understanding of AD, which is not to be answered in a short comment